# Dual boot RHEL and Ubuntu using BIOS / LVM (separate partitions same RAIDed disk)

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, boot, partition, dual-boot

NOTE; I already did a backup so its ok if I loose data.

I need to set up a dual boot system on baremetal dell server.
Must be installed on one hard drive. The hard drive is a RAID 1 of two disks.
I created two separate partitions on the RAIDed drive.

Originally only Ubuntu was installed.
I shrunk the partition, and made a new file system. Then installed RHEL. RHEL installed the file system as a LVM. Here are their roles now.

```
ubuntu lvm = /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 & /dev/sda3
RHEL lvm =   /dev/sda4 & /dev/sda5
```

However after installing RHEL on the /dev/sda4, I can no longer boot to Ubuntu and the one Dell shot boot selection screen only sees RHEL.

After booting to rhel doing a `lsblk` I can see `/dev/sda3` is still intact, but I am not sure how I can access it. I can only assume I messed something up and the boot loader for Ubuntu OS access.

Is there anyway I can set up a boot selection screen to get to the Ubuntu LVM, and RHEL LVM? Is there anyway I can switch between these systems now?

EDIT: I am editing to add a few answers to questions others have (All commands are being run the RHEL system):
The partitions were ext4 but after installing the OS's they are LVMs

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                my3UqB-2evu-HZT6-Jvnn-GKfK-hi47-RVdw0u
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2022-08-23 16:40:51 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                os7cjL-DSI2-Rz5z-wRWV-LYfP-tDmG-VayFTE
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2022-08-23 16:40:52 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <120.31 GiB
  Current LE             30799
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                V0mplL-eCiW-Rt4B-ZKpG-ryht-4AHw-oYCT86
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2022-08-23 16:40:52 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                70.00 GiB
  Current LE             17920
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                NVa00w-MfYG-GQYc-dYKy-1BBZ-gZzC-5y5YDc
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2021-05-12 11:01:54 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                245.62 GiB
  Current LE             62879
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:3

# file -sL /dev/sd*
/dev/sda:  DOS/MBR boot sector
/dev/sda1: data
/dev/sda2: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=cf3f54c0-8c15-4d21-86ff-17bdf992731c (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/sda3: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: dHelg8-yeT9-6MbX-Ww60-kHiB-1e5X-qaWaDA, size: 478483054592
/dev/sda4: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 512, v2 dirs)
/dev/sda5: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: ibSB6r-o56m-tGZj-QgWP-MUCk-dTsE-mO0qov, size: 208641458176
/dev/sdb:  writable, no read permission
```

The boot partition for RHEL is `sda4`. User data is `sda5`. (I edited above `sda` breakdowns). For Ubuntu, the boot partition might have been `sda1` or `sda2`, user data is on `sda3`.

Both systems are using BIOS boot.

I can see the logical petitions from RHEL:

```
# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 446.6G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part
├─sda3                      8:3    0 250.3G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:3    0 245.6G  0 lvm
├─sda4                      8:4    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda5                      8:5    0 194.3G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root             253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rhel-swap             253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rhel-home             253:2    0 120.3G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I can mount sda2 only (which appears to be the boot partition for Ubuntu.) The other paritions I cannot.

```
~]# find /mnt
/mnt
/mnt/ubuntu_sda3
/mnt/ubuntu_sda1
/mnt/ubuntu_sda2
[root@localhost ~]# sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ubuntu_sda1
mount: /mnt/ubuntu_sda1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
[root@localhost ~]# sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu_sda2
[root@localhost ~]# sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/ubuntu_sda3
mount: /mnt/ubuntu_sda3: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
[root@localhost ~]# ls /mnt/ubuntu_sda2
config-4.15.0-189-generic  grub                           initrd.img-4.15.0-191-generic  System.map-4.15.0-189-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-189-generic
config-4.15.0-191-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-189-generic  lost+found                     System.map-4.15.0-191-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-191-generic
```

I did find [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member) online for being able to mount sda3, but I am holding off just in case this would mess something up.

Comment: I do not know lvm, but someone that does may want more details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  You do have unique /boot partitions? And both installed in same boot mode, both UEFI or both old BIOS mode?

Comment: This is confusing. Do you have ext4 file systems on `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4` or are these lvm volumes? What boot partition is being used? Perhaps `/dev/sda1`? Is this BIOS or EFI? From RHEL, can you see the logical volumes on `/dev/sda3` and can you mount them?

Comment: @doneal24 I updated my answer to clarify your questions, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @oldfred, I am not clear on what your asking, you mention a pastebin link but I dont see one in your comment. Also I dont have access to Ubuntu anymore, so do I need to run boot-repair off a live Ubuntu image?

Comment: If you go to the link on Boot-Repair & run it. It will then offer to run a Boot-Info Summary Report & that will also offer to upload to a pastebin site. Post link into your question above. Click on link & follow directions.Any working Ubuntu and most other Linux will run Boot-Repair. You always need a working live installer for current installed version to make repairs. You can use Boot-Repair's ISO, but it often is not updated as often as ppa.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
There was not much to do since I am using BIOS. I just needed to update the grub bootloader config. It literally added Ubuntu to the grub loading screen automatically.

1. I updated RHEL (optional)
2. Updated grub with this command `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` Doing this I noticed that "Ubuntu 18.04 was found". Note, if you were running a Debian based system and wanted to update grub `update-grub` does the same thing, just did not have this command in RHEL.
3. Reboot.
4. Wait for boot loader screen to appear. Now Ubuntu lines appear. I can select RHEL or Ubuntu, and the OS loads to either.